# GitKraken is very slow since macOS Big Sur update

Tags: macos, gitkraken, macos-big-sur

Since I upgraded to Big Sur, everything seems really slow on Gitkraken (checkout, pull/push, commits...)

I tried reinstalling it but it didn't change.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

**Edit Feb 16 2022:**

Axosoft released `8.3` version of Gitkraken which seems to fix the issue:

> Mac users will get optimal performance without needing to run the 'Big Sur workaround' from a terminal, which had been required to fix the partial signature issue introduced in macOS Big Sur.

**Previous answer:**

I got an answer from their support, saying I have to run

```
codesign --remove-signature /Applications/GitKraken.app/Contents/Frameworks/GitKraken\ Helper\ \(Renderer\).app
```

And everything is now working smoothly again. Yay!

Here is their full answer:

> Thank you for using GitKraken! This is currently a known issue with the new Mac Big Sur OS.
>
> As a workaround, consider running the following command in your terminal:
> codesign --remove-signature /Applications/GitKraken.app/Contents/Frameworks/GitKraken\ Helper\ (Renderer).app
>
> This temporary workaround removes the GitKraken Signature (making it a partially-signed app) which means if you update GitKraken you will need to do this again. However, this should help with the performance for now while we wait for Apple to address this issue.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Hopefully Axosoft and Apple release a more permanent solution soon

Comment: This workaround has been officially published on Axosoft's blog: https://blog.axosoft.com/workaround-gitkraken-big-sur-issues/

Comment: I was stuck with this and thought that it is just the way it is now, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Worked for me to. Had the same issue with VSCode where the same 'codesign remove-signature' command fixed the issue

Comment: Why does removing the signature make it run faster? Signatures are only checked when the process is started, so why does this work?

Comment: @Dai You can have a look at the open issue of this lib used by Gitkraken : https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/3050

Comment: I guess Apple hasn't "fixed" it yet. 2 Big Sur updates have been released since the slow down and it's still slow, but only on my iMac. My Macbook Air is not having the slow issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was starting to think that there was something wrong with my mac. This worked wonders.

Comment: Seems, not working on Monterey, sadly I lose my day work, thx for this bug